# trigger a button with click and keypress in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a lot of buttons in my web tool. I have .click() events for each of them. I am not sure how to add a keyboard shortcut along with the click so that the user can either click the button or press a key (e.g 'k') on the keyboard to call the button function.

```
$('#myButton').click(function () {
        // here is my code to be run when clicked
    });
```

how to add for example 'k' key to this button.
I also want to be able to disable the click and keypress at some point. So how can I then disable both of the event listeners?

Comment: If I use $(document), how can I unbind it later?

Comment: It looks like you're using jQuery so you can use `$(document).off('keypress')`. See https://api.jquery.com/off/

Answer (score 2):

```
var myButton=document.querySelector("#myButton");
document.body.addEventListener("keydown",function(){
    var code=75; // 75 is keycode of 'k'
    if(event.keyCode==code)
    {
        myButton.click();
    }
});
```

Here keydown event is added to body so that when a user clicks a key (here it is k), the myButton will be 'clicked', which is it's click event handler will be executed.

To get the `keyCodes` visit this site [keycode.info](https://keycode.info/) or try console logging keycodes when pressing the keys.